# I'm trying to make a file context menu customization

Tags: windows-registry, context-menu, windows-11

I'm trying to add a context menu item for rendering `.blend` files.

`"C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\blender.exe" -b (file path) -a` works fine in the run window and command prompt, but I don't know how that translates to the command in the registry. I've created a `render` key and a `command` key in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shell\`. It opens the file in blender, but the command's actual function of rendering it (and without launching the gui) clearly doesn't work.

Can anybody help?

Comment: The context menu for Windows 11 received some pretty massive changes, it's context-sensitive, meaning the contents will change based on where it's opened.  What used to be possible might no longer be possible.   You might have to wait for Windows 11 22H2 to achieve what you want.

Comment: @Ramhound Why exactly would that be?

Comment: The current Windows Insider Preview build has some context menu changes. Most of those changes should be in Windows 10 22H2.  There will also be a way to view the old context menu with a simpler keyboard shortcut.  If that were to happen, you would be able to modify the legacy context menu more than likely, but until it's release there is no way of knowing.